# WebBrowser not executing Google Analytics Javascript

Tags: c#, browser-automation

I have a website running locally and I want to test the GA code I have by hitting the website repeatedly (with a delay) using C#'s `WebBrowser` class. The issue is that the GA code (the event) is sent with `$('document').ready()` and I cannot for the life of me get `WebBrowser` to actually load the javascript on the page.

I was able to get this to work by using Chrome or Firefox by using `var proc = new Process("firefox.exe", "my-ga-args")` and that works, but I'd like to run this in the background while I'm doing other work and even if I modify the process to start minimized it still takes focus away from my main window when it closes and re-opens Firefox (using different GA parameters that I have in a list that its looping through).

So, is there any way to get `WebBrowser` to actually execute javascript that exists on the webpage *and* have it hidden from view while running?

Comment: I am not sure about this issue, but CefSharp is a great way to add browser support to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [Google's Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or given your C# tag, perhaps the .NET port [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp).

> ... library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.